# hook_file_download triggered twice on Firefox

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm using a clean slate Firefox Quantum 63 testing my Drupal 8 website. It is well working on Chrome and IE but Firefox fired twice on `hook_file_download` API (some nodes automatically created twice). Any idea why this happened?

my hook looks like this:

```
function hook_file_download($uri) {
    $node = Node::create([
        'type'    =>  'article',
        ...
    ]);
    $node->save();
}
```

Comment: The browser must be requesting the file download twice, there isn't really another explanation

Comment: @Clive but why only on Firefox?

Comment: You would need to ask someone familiar with Firefox, I don't use it I'm afraid

Comment: Ccould it be related to FIrefox prefetching? See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections. See prefetching section.

Comment: @sanzante tested, still have the same problem.